# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_x^{tx} f(s) s^{-1}ds$

Tags: limits

I am trying to find: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_x^{tx} f(s) s^{-1}ds$ and we are given that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =0$ and $t>1$.

Intuitively, since the bounds of the integral are both going to infinity, can't we immediately say that the limit will be zero?

The actual solution I have is that:
given the limit behaviour of $f(x)$ and some constant $\epsilon$, there exists $T$ such that $-\epsilon < f(x)<\epsilon$ where $x \ge T$.

So:

$$
-\epsilon \log t = -\epsilon \int_x^{tx}s^{-1}ds \le \int_x^{tx} f(s) s^{-1}ds \le \epsilon \int_x^{tx}s^{-1}ds  = \epsilon \log(t)
$$
and it follows that the limit is zero. I understand the progression but I don't quite see how the conclusion follows. Why is it that we may conclude the limit is zero if we bound the function by $-\epsilon \log t,\epsilon \log t$?

Comment: Note that $t$ is fixed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I'm still not quite understanding why 
$$
-\epsilon \log t \le  \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_x^{tx} f(s) s^{-1}ds \le \epsilon \log(t)
$$
implies that the limit is zero though

Comment: Given any $\epsilon'\gt 0$, we can by taking $x$ large enough make the integral $\\gt  -\epsilon'$ and $\lt \epsilon'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:*
Let $a > 0$; let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$; if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $|f(x)|  \leq a\varepsilon$ for large $x$, what should we say about the behavior of $f$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Could you elaborate now it's been accepted?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Alternatively: $|f(x)| = o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$, so? If you are still in doubt, note that for every $\delta > 0$ we have $|f(x)| < a\cdot \frac{\delta}{a} = \delta$ for large $x$.